# How to schedule tasks without Quartz

Tags: java, job-scheduling

Can anyone tell,advice how to run a scheduler without Quartz in java. I want to implement such features that if application server remain stop , my scheduler will run. So I thought the executable class to place outside of the war file. So can anyone give me suggestion ? Thanks.

Comment: If you want it to run even when the server is down, maybe a cron job could work?

Comment: Is your question about scheduling tasks without Quartz or how to do it when your application is not running? Or both?

Comment: @EvertonAgner : My question execute job when application is not running.

Comment: Did I answer your question? If so, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding scheduling tasks without `Quartz`, you can use Java's [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
    public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); }
};

// Beeps every 10 seconds
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Now, regarding doing it when your application is not running, I see three options:

- Develop a stand-alone application with your scheduled tasks, decoupled from your webapp
- Look up for Application Server features for that purpose
- OS scheduled tasks, as Linux's cron job

Comment: Whoops, that's a typo

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I have one question , where the class to be placed?

Comment: If you want to code it with the ScheduledExecutorService, I would recommend you to take the first approach, developing a different application with your Scheduled Tasks.